# How to make boxplots from a list of (variable length) vectors

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a `list` of 40 numeric vectors. My question is how can I do one box plot for each vector and group every 4 box plots to a single position on the x-axis.

That is the x-axis will have 10 ticks and every tick has 4 box plots. Additionally I would like to colour the box plots by their order in the group.

Here is a small sample of the data (two groups):

```
list(
  c(1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 33, 12),
  c(5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  c(4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4),
  c(2, 2, 21, 1, 4),
  c(3, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  c(2, 2, 3, 1, 1),
  c(6, 5, 3, 4, 5)) -> 
ll
```

Comment: There probably is a simple solution with something like `ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(unit, fill=method), position="dodge")`, but you'd need to provide more precise details on what eg 'similar lengths' mean.. Try to provide an actual sample of the data.

Comment: I do not know why I got three negative scores. The relevant answer that I found was for a data frame that all rows have similar size.

Comment: the down votes are probably because it would take a heroic effort to understand correctly what is the type and shape of your data. I understand quite clearly what kind of output you need, but I'm really confused about the input data. Is it a `list` of `list`s, is it a `data.frame` ? Are there two `data.frame`s ?

Comment: @liborm, Thanks for your reply, I edited my question and add some sample data

Comment: In this case, 4 fisrt rows are the results of four different methods that need to present on a unit of x-axis. The next four rows (5 to 8) are the same methods that need to be represented on the seconed unit of x-axis

Comment: `dput(your_object[c(1:4, 20:24])` would be much better, because one can then paste it to R and work from that point. Check `reprex`. Your x-axis is categorical then. What is your y-axis? Just guessing - sum of values for each position? That is 8 bars for first x-axis tick?

Comment: sorry, misread the question a bit, you want a box plot per list item (not a bar chart) .. just paste the data in loadable way and we can work on that.

Comment: @scoa After the edits I believe the question is quite straight forward, understandable and justifiable. Is there anything else that can be done to put it back on track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create boxplots from a list of numeric vectors and group it into four-tuples, you need to do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# ll is the list of vectors 
map_df(ll, 
   function(x) data.frame(val = x), 
   .id = "row") %>% 
  mutate(
    row = as.numeric(row) - 1,
    grp = floor(row / 4) %>% as.factor,
    method = (row %% 4) %>% as.factor) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(grp, val, fill=method), position = "dodge")
```

In brief: `map_df` converts each vector to a data frame with one column, then row-binds them all, adding a column named `row` which identifies where did the original row came from, `mutate` converts `row` to 0 based numeric and adds `grp` and `method` columns based on the original vector index (every fourth is next group using modulo), `ggplot` initializes the plot, `geom_boxplot` adds a box plot layer taking the data from the table.

---

Output for the sample data (a little ugly because of the outliers).

[image: output for the sample data]